# Replacing a string in a VSTS Release Pipeline in files gives Access Denied

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have setup an automated release pipeline for my website. It is built with Hugo, so I'm only FTP-ing a couple if files during the release. Until now it worked fine.

I'm trying to add a staging environment. To get the URLs in the static files to be correct want to replace a dummy url (say "http://DUMMYURL.com") to the correct one for the environment (staging or production).

I've tried using a Regex replace task (https://github.com/knom/vsts-regex-tasks/) and the standard PowerShell task to replace these strings but I keep getting an access denied error.

Here's an example log:
[image: ErrorLog]

I don't want to build the website again for every individual environment. I start to wonder if it is even possible to replace a string during a release. But if it can be done, how can I fix the access denied errors?

Comment: Are you releasing on premise with a local agent? Is it running as Network Service?

Comment: No, I'm running on online and on a hosted agent.

Comment: @Sorskoot Could you share your build/release definition?  How did you specify `Search Paths to Input Files` argument? If you specify only one file, how's the result?

Comment: Add the file extension in the search pattern and then try again.

Comment: @Sorskoot did you get any solution of your problem, actually i am newbie on azure and my requirement is quite same.

Comment: I never found a solution, sorry. I test this website locally and publish only to production. If I have some time I might look into it again. If I find a solution I add it here.